# Reboot loop after Windows XP Service Pack 3 update

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, sp3, reboot

Recently I upgraded to Service Pack 3, and now it seems that something has gone terribly wrong with the update.

After logging in, my computer will blue screen after about 5 minutes and then go into a reboot loop (I don't have the exact error message handy).

I have a Sager NP2092 notebook, running an Intel chipset.

I'd rather avoid having to reformat my XP, especially with my copy of Windows 7 arriving right around the corner.

After doing some Googling, I came across this article: [Does your AMD-based computer boot after installing XP SP3?](http://msinfluentials.com/blogs/jesper/archive/2008/05/08/does-your-amd-based-computer-boot-after-installing-xp-sp3.aspx)

However, it deals with the AMD chips, and specifically states not to use its fix on Intel based systems.

**EDIT**
After killing the reboot, this is the error that pops up:

STOP: 0x000000F4 (0x00000003, 0x8A187118, 0x8A18728C, 0x80604438)

**EDIT2**
I have run Memtest86, and it reported 0 errors.

Comment: Can you get into safe mode?

Comment: Yes I can, last night I did a System Restore to a few days ago (ie before the SP3 update), but the issue still remains.

Comment: The reason I ask is so that you can tell the computer NOT to reboot after a blue screen, so that you can see what's causing the problem.

Comment: Just in case, run memtest86 or the equivalent.  It's perfectly possible the problem is an unrelated hardware fault.

Comment: memtest86 has been run, with no errors reported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as much as I hated to do this...I ran out of options and needed my computer back.
I installed Windows 7 RC and will have to migrate to the released version when it comes out soon.

Thanks for all your answers, but unfortunately none were able to rectify my specific situation.

Comment: Well, if that worked, it's better than you're computer not working :)

Comment: definitely...i was quite happy to see the memtest86 pass with no hardware failures...that was really the biggest relief!

Answer (score 2):

See this article about [Stop: 0x000000F4](http://www.techsupportforum.com/microsoft-support/windows-xp-support/181457-stop-0x000000f4.html), where the Stop parameters seem to be similar to yours.

Since restoring to a previous restore-point didn't fix the problem, I would go out on a limb and guess that a hardware problem just happened by coincidence just after the SP3 installation. This might of course be a bit far-fetched, but is worth checking.

See the above thread for the solutions found. For some people this was as simple as replacing the CMOS battery.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue between xp sp3 and some amd processors that will cause a cyclic reboot. This is caused by an uneeded intel driver that must be remvoed from teh registry. Search google if your stil linterested in resolutions.

Answer (score -4):

if asked personally i have heard rumors that the sp 3 has many bugs so its no good to upgrade from sp2

About the problem i request u to never upgrade any windows from patches as even i have faced the same with Vista & Xp Proffessional If u need to upgrade your desktop it is advisible to get an os of that version rather than just that upgrade patch.

I dont know about mac but what i have seen is that lpptops come with a customised O.S. so 
it is advisible not to do any thing with the laptops...........

Comment: I definitely disagree. Do your bug fixes and security updates. Not doing them puts your system at risk. Also, at work we rolled out SP3 to every one of our 300+ XP desktops. They work fine, no worse than SP2.